# Xamarin - WebView update URL from another page/view

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a very basic tabbed application
On page one is a web view using Xamarin.Forms

```
 <WebView x:Name="webview1" IsVisible="true" Source="" ></WebView>
```

I can update the URL of this view from the .cs code behind using for example

```
 webview1.Source = "http://www.microsoft.com"
```

I have a second tab which I'm using for settings/additional info.
On this second page I have a button which on click I want to reset the web view on Page 1 to a new Url / updates the Source.

Just trying to reference it on second page tells me I can't due to protection level and an object reference for a static item is required.

updated:

```
public partial class launcher5Page : ContentPage
{
    public launcher5Page()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        webview1.Source = "web address here";
    }

    public static bool changeURL(string urlString)
    {
        webview1.Source = urlString;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Still getting 
Error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member

Comment: just create a public method (or property) on the page that sets the Source of the webview, and then call that from your other page

Comment: you can't use a static method to modify a specific instance of a class

Comment: an example snippet would be great please, I'm going round in circles trying to find answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using the `MessagingCenter` for such a job. Then you could do this:

```
public partial class launcher5Page : ContentPage {

    public launcher5Page() {
        InitializeComponent();

        webview1.Source = "web address here";

        /* Normally you want to subscribe in OnAppearing and unsubscribe in OnDisappearing but since another page would call this, we need to stay subscribed */
        MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<string>(this, "ChangeWebViewKey");
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string>(this, "ChangeWebViewKey", newWebViewUrl => Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
            webview1.Source = newWebViewUrl;
        }));
    }
}
```

Then on your other page:

```
 Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send("https://www.google.com", "ChangeWebViewKey");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `changeURL` method is marked `static`, meaning that it cannot use anything that isn't marked static. [Learn more about what **static** means.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/98f28cdx.aspx).

Since the class `launcher5Page` is a partial class, one imagines that the `webview1` variable used in the snippet is defined in the different parts of the class. `webview1` is called a `member` of class `launcher5Page` as it is defined outside of any method, and inside the class.

Your solution: remove the `static` keyword from your `changeURL` method, or make the `webview1` member `static` so that other `static` members such as `changeURL` can use it.

```
public **partial** class launcher5Page : ContentPage
{
    public launcher5Page()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        webview1.Source = "web address here";
    }

    public **static** bool changeURL(string urlString)
    {
        **webview1**.Source = urlString;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Also all of this has absolutely nothing to do with Xamarin, other than Xamarin being a set of libraries written in c#. Your problem lies completely in your lack of knowledge of  the c# language.